# Topology basis consisting of convex sets in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, convexity-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. For all points $x,y \in X$ we define the **metric segment** between them as the following set:

$$\left [ x,y \right ] =  \left \{ z \in X : d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,y)\right \}$$

We then say that a set $S\subseteq X$ is **convex** if for all $x,y \in S$ it holds true that $\left [ x,y \right ] \subseteq S$. Denote by $\tau$ the topology on $X$ induced by the metric $d$.

My question is *does there exist a family $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \tau$ of convex sets such that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$?*

It should be noted that open and closed balls in metric spaces are not necessarily convex sets. Also, arbitrary intersection of convex sets in metric spaces is a convex set. Thus, we can define convex hulls.

Comment: Put additional information about your question in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X=\ell^1$.  I claim that the convex hull (in your sense) of any ball in $X$ is unbounded, so there are no bounded open convex (in your sense) sets in $X$.  By symmetry it suffices to consider the closed unit ball $B$ centered at $0$.  Let $e_n$ denote the sequence whose $n$th entry is $1$ and all other entries are $0$.  Then each $e_n$ is in $B$.  But if $n\neq m$, then $e_n+e_m\in[e_n,e_m]$, so $e_n+e_m$ is in the convex hull of $B$.  Similarly, if $i,j,k,\ell$ are distinct, then $e_i+e_j+e_k+e_\ell\in[e_i+e_j,e_k+e_\ell]$ and thus is in the convex hull of $B$.  Continuing this process, we conclude that for any $N$, any sum of $2^N$ distinct $e_n$'s is in the convex hull of $B$.  Thus the convex hull is unbounded.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "eventually 0"?

Comment: I meant that all but finitely many entries are $0$, but actually that was irrelevant--you can just use all of $\ell^1$.

Comment: I suppose that by this inductive process, for example, the sequence (1, 1, 1, 1, ...) is in the convex hull of B? The unboundedness of the convex hull of B would then follow by the fact that the sequence (0, 0, 0, 0, ...) is also an element. Is this a reasonable conclusion?

Comment: If convex sets formed a basis then there would have to be bounded convex open sets since balls are bounded.  You can't get a sequence $(1,1,1,1,\dots)$ with infinitely many $1$s but you can get an arbitrarily large finite number of $1$s which implies the convex hull is unbounded.